# Generating realizations of sampling distributions

Tags: sampling, biostatistics, ranking, nonparametric

I have a sample of $N$ individuals. I know (assume) that the distribution of species' abundances follows a particular form, e.g., negative binomial. A nested example of these kinds of distributions is below. (This figure assumes non-integer abundances are possible. Mine would not.)

[image]

The catch is that I do not know the number of species in my sample. I only know the total number of individuals. I want to calculate the number of species and their abundances given a particular distribution of species abundances. Abundances will have integer values.

How can I generate a realization of species and their abundances from the assumed form (e.g., negative binomial) and the total number of individuals? Numeric solutions are fine.

*Further thoughts:* I think there's a very elementary integration step that I'm not seeing.
I know what to do for a related problem in which I have a list of species and the abundance of each: For a given sample $N$, I can use a multinomial to draw realizations using relative abundances.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but I can't work out what's going on from your description. Abundances are integers? If so, how can they be asserted to be "e.g. lognormal"? I also don't follow how the parts of whatever it is that's going on here are related. Can you give a mathematical (algebraic) description of the components of this (and their relationships), or at the least a numerical example (from which the variables and relationships might - with some luck - be inferred)?

Comment: I added a figure and clarified the explanation. I probably wouldn't be here if I could see the math more clearly! Help welcome.

Comment: I understand that you have difficulty and that's why you're here (I've answered over a thousand questions here, I do know how it can be), but you must understand that we may not even know the precise definitions of your variables, let alone how they're supposed to be related. How can we give advice if we can't fully understand the problem? When abundances can be two different things that seems to make it quite hard to follow.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it less general.